# jQuery.delay() is not a function error

Tags: jquery, jquery-1.5

I have used the same code as below

```
jQuery(elem).slideDown("slow").delay(3000).slideUp("slow");
```

That was worked fine some months before. Now it is showing error as

`jQuery(elem).slideDown("slow").delay` is not a function

now I'm using jQuery 1.5.

Comment: Provide the html code. Also, check if js with jQuery is loaded

Comment: What is `elem`? Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hT4Pk/1/

Comment: possible duplicate of [`delay` is not a function (jQuery 1.3)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5343317/delay-is-not-a-function-jquery-1-3)