# `delay` is not a function (jQuery 1.3)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the error i'm getting from Firebug using jQuery in a function outside (and before) the `$(document).ready` because it is used in a inline onclick event:

```
$("#_box").fadeIn(500).delay is not a function
$('#_box').fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
```

and this is the function:

```
function throwBox(message) {
    $('#_box').html(message);
    $('#_box').fadeIn(500).delay(3000).fadeOut(500);
}
```

Isn't `delay()` a jQuery function?
What happens in my browser is that the `fadeIn()` function is called nicely and the box appear, but then stands there and doesn't disappear.

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?.. `delay()` was added in 1.4 http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I loaded an old copy of jQuery (1.3) instead of the new one while `delay()` was added in version 1.4 as suggested by Quintin Robinson.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delay/
version added: 1.4

Very conviniently labeled in the jQuery API. :)

Comment: @Quintin Robinson, thanks very much. I didn't even faced the problem of the version thinking that delay was one of the first functions added to the Framework. :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're stuck using jQuery 1.3 (maybe you're working with Drupal 6) a work-around is to animate a property that's constant.

For example, replace:

```
$("#id").delay(1000).fadeOut();
```

With:

```
$("#id").animate({top: 0}, 1000).fadeOut();
```